# Hilt Unsupported metadata version in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I was tried to run my code in Kotlin 1.5.10
With plugin as

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

and dependencies as below

```
dependencies {
    ...
    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.33-beta"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
```

When I migrate to kotlin_version = "1.5.10", it just errors out stating

> error: [Hilt]
> Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
> at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:206)
> at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:186)
> at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133)
> ...

Can anyone help me? I spent a lot of time on it, your answer will help me a lot

Comment: Try to update all hilt libraries to the latest versions

Comment: I was tried, but it has the same issue

Comment: Update your Hilt version to the latest (2.36 at the moment)

Comment: it's not working for me

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Go to https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup check Hilt currently version

***Update:*** For now, you can use the newest version.

`Kotlin:1.9.0` with `Hilt:2.48`

Comment: Thanks for the answer,upgrading the hilt library is a nightmare at times.

Comment: Also these versions work for me: kotlin:1.6.0 , hilt:2.40.5

Comment: This worked for me, I used the answer provided by @NazaninNasab since it has more up to date versions. cheers

Comment: I would add: **Visit the Gradle Build Setup page and verify EVERYTHING is up to date in your build.gradle files**. Android Studio with it's suggestions helped me update only a part, but the Hilt Gradle Plugin was not, so I ended up having new and old version numbers that were causing the error.

Comment: for me the gradle plugin was out of date, updating it to match the hilt version resolved my problem.

Comment: For some reason my project built fine on my normal desktop computer but I was getting this Hilt "unsupported metadata version" error when I cloned the repo onto my Surface tablet. But upgrading my Hilt Gradle plugin from 2.40.1 (I think that's what it was) to 2.42 (Kotlin Gradle plugin was already 1.7.0) fixed it. Appreciate it big dawg, I don't know anything about all this Gradle/dependencies crap.

Comment: Man, android development sucks. You spend more than 50% of the time solving dependencies and compatibility problems than actual work.

Comment: I've been battling with this issue for two days now...your solution finally  worked...THANKS!

Comment: Worked for me
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
to
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.0" apply false

Comment: Thanks for me Kotlin:1.7.0 with Hilt:2.42 this combination works perfectly

Answer (score 74):

Here how i solved the error:

If you are using Kotlin 1.9.0
then use hilt 2.48

Make these Updates in Hilt version:

in Project-level build.gradle

```
    plugins{
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
}
```

in App-level build.gradle

```
 plugins{
 id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

dependencies{
     implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
        kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
    }
```

Comment: Great! The best answer!

Comment: Thanks mate, It worked for me for the latest version.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! I had some time struggling with this

Answer (score 22):

If anyone still facing this issue related to not matching version of kotlin and hilt here is the latest version of hilt vs kotlin that is working for me

project level:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48.1" apply false
}
```

app level:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48.1")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")

}
```

I wasted around 30 hr just to figure out proper latest version and compatibility where I was stuck with the same reported error. hope this will help someone!

Comment: This was the fix! Good work! kapt annotation was the trick.

Comment: Thanks alot... Shubham for solution i was facing same issue since 3 days after update android studio. now got resolved

Comment: Happy for you bro

Comment: 2 days of looking and searching came to an end thanks a lot

Answer (score 20):

I got the same error. I changed two gradle files and It worked for me.

Project Gradle

```
plugins {
   
    //    dependencies for dagger hilt
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.42' apply false

}
```

Module Gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42'
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")

}
```

Comment: The error is related to compatibility issues between hilt and kotlin. Updating Hilt might work but you will also have to look at Kotlin compatibility whether it needs to be upgraded or not.

Comment: Your solution worked with me, thanks <3

Answer (score 17):

If you use kotlin version 1.8.0 then

in Project-level build.gradle change hilt version

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
```

In App-level build.gradle

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
```

Answer (score 8):

### Updated: Kotlin DSL

Using dagger version `2.48` with `ksp` also resolved this issue. Using Java version `17`.

**build.gradle.kts (project)**

```
plugins {
    ...

    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
}
```

**build.gradle.kts (app)**

```
plugins {
   ...   

   id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
   id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

...

dependencies {
   ...

   implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
   ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48")
}
```

### Old Solution

I resolved the error by updating the dependency version to the latest version and adding this additional dependency. I am using `java version 17`.

```
kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"
```

**build.gradle (Project Level)**

```
plugins {
   ...

   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
   id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.48' apply false
}
```

**build.gradle (App Level)**

```
plugins {
   ...   
   
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
   id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

...

dependencies {
   ...

   implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48"
   kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48"
   kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the answer , i had to do a slight tweak in order to work for me because i'm using Arctic Fox, hopefully this answer will help as well

Build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
ext {
    compose_version = '1.0.0'
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha05'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37"
}
}
```

Build.gradle (app)

```
//Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.34-beta"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.34-beta"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding this line to build.gradle dependencies helped me:

```
kapt("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.3.0")
```

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45885

Answer (score 5):

If any solution solved your problem. Go to https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup, in *Using Hilt with Kotlin* section, copy the version mentioned in `dependencies` and update your `build.gradle` accordingly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is the Right way of resolving the error on latest SDK

Comment: I would suggest this but only to improve the answer to verify the versions used in gradle as a complement to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68319048/1084764

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin 1.7.10, you just need to make the hilt versions 2.42.

Comment: What if I am not using hilt in my android app?

Answer (score 4):

in Project-level build.gradle change hilt version

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
```

in App-Level build.gradle

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
```

Answer (score 2):

I got same here. I was using dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta with Kotlin 1.5.10.Please try this

Project gradle

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta"
```

Module gradle

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
dependencies {
    ...
    //dagger-hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.35.1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
kotlin_version = "1.8.10"
hilt_version = "2.45"
```

That are the newest versions

Answer (score 2):

check the `hilt_version_one` is same to `hilt_version_two`

I get the problem ,  when my two version is different .

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "$hilt_version_one" apply false
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version_two"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version_two"
```

Answer (score 1):

general solution - in AS build console click link at bottom - build with `-stacktrace` param and find which annotation processor (KAPT) is causing error - then try to update dependency - if you are lucky new version should be available and supporting your gradle version

message in build output you should lookin for

```
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. It's for dependency/library version error and debug option shows the actual reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have face this issue twice,

So two possible solution for this problem:

Case 1: If you are using new version of Android such as 1.8 or 1.9

Simply update the version of dagger.hilt into the new one 2.48

Classpath:

```
plugins {
     id "com.google.dagger.hilt.android" version "2.42" apply false
}
```

and dependency :

```
 implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48"
```

Case 2: If you are using previous version of Android such as 1.7 or less than you have to make sure that the classpath and dependency version match, in my case the error was because of different version.

Mismatch:

Classpath:

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.dagger.hilt.android" version "2.42" apply false
}
```

and dependency :

```
 implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48"
```

Correct:

Classpath:

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.dagger.hilt.android" version "2.42" apply false
}
```

and dependency :

```
 implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42"
   kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by different versions specified in the dependencies:

- `2.40` in `classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin'`
- `2.43.2` in `implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android'`

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue when upgrading `kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.x` for fulfill requirement of `compose`. I revert them to `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21` and `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` value

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```

> kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly check helt dependency versions with below url

https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup

Check you kotlin versions

Kotlin version 1.6.0

Project level gradle
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40"

App level gradle
def hilt_version="2.40"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"


Kotlin version 1.7.0

Project level gradle
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42"

App level gradle
def hilt_version="2.42"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that the Hilt version in the implementation and the classpath were different, making them the same solved the issue. A good practice should be using a version variable.

They were like this: In the build.gradle file of the app module

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.39.1"
In the build.gradle file of the project

classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1'

Answer (score 0):

My solution: if you use dagger 2 and hilt in one project, you should keep versions the same

```
hiltVersion = '2.48.1'
daggerVersion = '2.48.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

So i am getting the same issue and after a lot of time spend i got to knew it's only version issue.
If you are using kotlin version

```
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
```

You can find it in your project level gardle.

The hilt version should be in project level gradle

```
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
```

and in app level gradle it should be

```
 implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
 kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
```