# Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0 after update some plugins

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I just updates the following plugins in my gradle files

```
 implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
```

and second gradle file I updated kotlin version

```
kotlin_version = "1.7.10"
```

then I got this error

```
error: [Hilt]
  Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
    at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:206)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:187)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1134)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadataFactory.create(KotlinMetadataFactory.java:56)
[Hilt]

    at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadataUtil.isObjectClass(KotlinMetadataUtil.java:91)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.RootMetadata.daggerCanConstruct(RootMetadata.java:207)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.RootMetadata.lambda$modulesThatDaggerCannotConstruct$0(RootMetadata.java:143)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.RootMetadata.modulesThatDaggerCannotConstruct(RootMetadata.java:145)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.RootMetadata.validate(RootMetadata.java:170)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.RootMetadata.createInternal(RootMetadata.java:71)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.RootMetadata.create(RootMetadata.java:57)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.ComponentTreeDepsProcessor.processComponentTreeDeps(ComponentTreeDepsProcessor.java:133)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.ComponentTreeDepsProcessor.postRoundProcess(ComponentTreeDepsProcessor.java:84)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.BaseProcessor.process(BaseProcessor.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.IsolatingProcessor.process(IsolatingProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.access$401(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.track(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.process(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:985)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:901)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1227)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1340)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:936)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.IncrementalCompileTask.call(IncrementalCompileTask.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.DefaultToolchainJavaCompiler.execute(DefaultToolchainJavaCompiler.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.lambda$createToolchainCompiler$1(JavaCompile.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompiler.execute(CleaningJavaCompiler.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory.lambda$createRebuildAllCompiler$0(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.SelectiveCompiler.execute(SelectiveCompiler.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.SelectiveCompiler.execute(SelectiveCompiler.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:279)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performIncrementalCompilation(JavaCompile.java:165)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:146)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
  
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
1 error

> Task :app:hiltJavaCompileDebug FAILED
```

this the full gradle projects/modules file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {

        // Versions for all the dependencies we plan to use. It's particularly useful for kotlin and
        // navigation where the versions of the plugin needs to be the same as the version of the
        // library defined in the app Gradle file
        kotlin_version = "1.7.10"
        version_gradle = "7.3.0"
        version_core = "1.8.0"
//        version_lifecycle_extensions = "2.2.0"
        hilt_version = "2.42"
        nav_version = "2.5.2"
        room_version = "2.4.3"
        version_constraint_layout = "2.2.0-alpha03"
//        version_glide = "4.12.0"
        version_retrofit = "2.9.0"
        version_recyclerview = "1.2.1"
        version_material = "1.6.1"
        version_play_services = "21.2.0"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$version_gradle"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1"
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'

    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "$version_gradle" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "$version_gradle" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this build gradle app dependices

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'

    implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1')
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This a known [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3448) with hilt and metatadata of kotlin version above 1.7.0**

currently, `Hilt:2.42` supports `Kotlin:1.7.0` so you need to downgrade to this version

also, keep following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67744002/7639296), and if there are any updates in the feature

Comment: thanks but after downgrade to version 1.7.0 I still got this error, anyway i downgraded to 1.6.21 i hope they fixed this issue soon

Comment: Similar issue with dagger2, resolved in the latest release https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/dagger-android/2.44.2