# Unable to solve a Hilt related error in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-hilt

I have an Android project written in Kotlin that uses Hilt. When I run the project, I get the following error:

```
error: [Hilt]   Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin
version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported
metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is = 1.0
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:200)
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)  
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataFactory.create(KotlinMetadataFactory.java:54)
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataUtil.isObjectClass(KotlinMetadataUtil.java:102)
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataUtil.isObjectOrCompanionObjectClass(KotlinMetadataUtil.java:119)
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.Processors.requiresModuleInstance(Processors.java:950)
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsProcessor.processModule(AggregatedDepsProcessor.java:169)
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsProcessor.processEach(AggregatedDepsProcessor.java:120)
    at
dagger.hilt.processor.internal.BaseProcessor.process(BaseProcessor.java:195)
    at
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
    at
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
    at
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
    at
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
    at
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
    at
```

I have written the program in Kotlin. I have attached the code for reference.
Here are the build.gradle files -

1. app level -

```
 plugins {
     id 'com.android.application'
     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
     id 'kotlin-kapt'
     id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' }

 android {
     namespace 'com.example.tazakhabar'
     compileSdk 34
 
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example.tazakhabar"
          minSdk 23
         targetSdk 34
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
 
         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
 

    buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
     compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8     }
     kotlinOptions {
         jvmTarget = '1.8'
     }
     buildFeatures{
         viewBinding true

     } }
 
 dependencies {
 
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
     implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

     // alternatively - just ViewModel
     implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
 
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
     implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'
     implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
     implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1'
 
 // alternatively - just LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
 
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3"))
 
 // Add the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library // When
 using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library
 dependencies
     implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
 
 }
```

2. Project level -

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
 to all sub-projects/modules. plugins {
     id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
     id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false }
```

I am new to Android programming, so I don’t know what’s causing the error. Any insight or suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because I guess the official android doc for hilt is not updated due to some reason . You need to follow the official hilt document just add the implementation as per the official hilt doc

update the version to this

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48'
```

for more  [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup) !

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the hilt-android dependency to the latest version. Your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68319048/16278843)