# Dagger-Hilt 2.4.4 with kotlin 1.9.0 ver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-hilt

When my Kotlin version was `1.9.0`, the **hilt** made the following error, but when I switched to version `1.7.21`, it works fine.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
error: [Hilt]
  Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:200)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataFactory.create(KotlinMetadataFactory.java:54)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataUtil.containsConstructorWithDefaultParam(KotlinMetadataUtil.java:176)
    at dagger.hilt.android.processor.internal.androidentrypoint.AndroidEntryPointMetadata.of(AndroidEntryPointMetadata.java:257)
    at dagger.hilt.android.processor.internal.androidentrypoint.AndroidEntryPointMetadata.of(AndroidEntryPointMetadata.java:184)
    at dagger.hilt.android.processor.internal.androidentrypoint.AndroidEntryPointProcessor.processEach(AndroidEntryPointProcessor.java:57)
    at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.BaseProcessor.process(BaseProcessor.java:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:311)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:257)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
[Hilt]
```

And when it's `1.9.0`, it works well if I use the `annotationProcessor` instead of `kapt` on this part. What's wrong with this?

```
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hilt Unsupported metadata version in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744002/hilt-unsupported-metadata-version-in-kotlin)

Comment: Use version 2.50 it work.  https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup

Comment: @Pawel Hi! I already solved this problem by change version to 2.48. But your reply was also helpful to me! Thanks!

Comment: @Vinay Thanks for your link! It was so helpful!