# Kotlin [Hilt] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message) Error

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, entity-relationship, dagger-hilt

I get the following errors when running the project, there is no problem in my codes, I think there may be a problem with the libraries I added, I am waiting for your help

[image]

MY **build.gradle.kts (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.22"
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs") version "2.7.7" apply false
}
```

My **build.gradle.kts (Module:App)**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")

}

android {
    namespace = "com.sertanozcnn.foodrecipes"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.sertanozcnn.foodrecipes"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
    dataBinding{
        enable = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    val nav_version = "2.7.7"
    val room_version = "2.6.1"

    implementation(fileTree("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar")))
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")

    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")

    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.5.0")

    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")

    implementation("com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0")
    implementation("com.todkars:shimmer-recyclerview:0.4.0")
    implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1")


    implementation("com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0")

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    kapt("androidx.databinding:databinding-common:8.2.2")
    kapt("com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4")



}
```

The error I get in :app:kaptDebugKotlin looks like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

I encountered this error while trying to pull recipes with Api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hilt Unsupported metadata version in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744002/hilt-unsupported-metadata-version-in-kotlin)